# Insert Data into SQL DB and Select PK and Store it into a session in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Is there a way to select the value of the PK of the inserted data into sql DB and then store it into a session on ASP.NET C#?

For example: I've insert something into the database. During that insert, I want to return that PK back to me and store it into a session.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree this is a somewhat vague question, but hopefully this will help.

Assuming this is SQL Server, you could use scope_identity(). Use a stored procedure to insert the row, and read back the value

e.g. assuming this table

```
create table Foo(FooId int identity(1,1) primary key, Field varchar(50))
```

create a procedure

```
create procedure dbo.usp_FooInsert 
    @fieldValue varchar(50)
as

insert into Foo(field) values(@fieldValue)

select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as InsertedFooId
go
```

Use the procedure in place of your current insert statement and read back the result.

Comment: Thanks. SCOPE_IDENTITY() works. I end up using (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); and it returns me with the ID of PK

Answer (score 0):

if the column is sorted, unique and int type you can alter it as PK.

Answer (score 0):

James answer is correct, but I want to add one point. You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT` or `@@IDENTITY` as per your requirement.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last IDENTITY value inserted into an IDENTITY column in the same scope.

`IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

`@@IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes

Comment: please upvote, if it has helped u